# Why format is strange when JSON is parsed in Swift3?

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

I have a struggle in parsing JSON data using Oxford Dictionary API. I can retrieve JSON data and at this point, there is no problem. But the format is a bit strange. In the example of JSON data by OXford Document, it looks like;

```
"results": [
{
  "id": "string",
  "language": "string",
  "lexicalEntries": [
    {
      "entries": [
        {..........
```

Unlike the example above, the array in my JSON is not surrouned by `[]`, but `()`
Why is this happening??

**Updated**

I used Alamofire to produce it. The code is;

```
   func getJSONData() {

    let appId = ""
    let appKey = ""
    let language = "en"
    let word = "play"
    let word_id = word.lowercased()
    let url = URL(string: "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/\(language)/\(word_id)")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue(appId, forHTTPHeaderField: "app_id")
    request.addValue(appKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "app_key")

    Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in
        print("Request \(response.request)")  // original URL request
        print("Response \(response.response)") // HTTP URL response
        print("Data \(response.data)")     // server data
        print("Result \(response.result)")   // result of response serialization

        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        }
    }
}
```

I followed all code in Oxford Dictionary Document, but the printed out JSON was far from the JSON in the document. So I tried to use Alamofire in the hope for it to work correctly, but the result was the same. https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/documentation

**Update2**

Okay, I understood why this was an error. To people who might have the same problem, I post the answer for the problem I had.

```
   enum JSONError: String, Error {
    case NoData = "ERROR: no data"
    case ConversionFailed = "ERROR: conversion from JSON failed"
}

func jsonParser() {

    let appId = ""
    let appKey = ""
    let language = "en"
    let word = "Ace"
    let word_id = word.lowercased() //word id is case sensitive and lowercase is required
    let url = URL(string: "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/\(language)/\(word_id)")!

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue(appId, forHTTPHeaderField: "app_id")
    request.addValue(appKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "app_key")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            guard let data = data else {
                throw JSONError.NoData
            }
            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary else {
                throw JSONError.ConversionFailed
            }

            if let stringJSON = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                print(stringJSON)
            }

            print(json)

        } catch let error as JSONError {
            print(error.rawValue)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

[Strange printed JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245445/strange-printed-json-format/38245533#38245533) This post helped me. This bugged me for a while. Thank you very much @EricAya

Comment: In printed response you may have array with `()`

Comment: *"Unlike the example above, the array in my JSON is not surrouned by [], but ()* Where are you seeing that? How have you produced it? What code are you using?

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0: This is my point. You're assuming that's where the OP is seeing them. You're *probably* right, but the question is incomplete without that information (and the code).

Comment: `the array in my JSON is not surrounded by [], but ()` Then it is not JSON. It probably *was* JSON but it's not JSON anymore. Do not confuse the JSON syntax with the Swift syntax with the NSArray syntax etc.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder agree with you ..

Comment: @Eric then how am I able to produce it as JSON?

Comment: First step: learn what is JSON, learn the syntax, see what is its purpose, look at the spec. Then learn what is a Swift array and what is an NSArray, and how each of these things looks like when printed. That's all, when done you will be able to use JSON properly. ;)

Comment: @EricAya Okay, I will learn that!!! Thanks!

Comment: @Ryo Cool. :) See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38245533/2227743 and http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a2227743%20json to kickstart your research. There's also many other similar Q&A already on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @EricAya Thank you very much! It worked! I I just should have made it String. Your advice helped me a lot!!!!

Comment: @Ryo You're welcome mate, I'm glad it helped.